# Where are unauthorized sudo attempts reported to?

Tags: sudo, logs

Where are unauthorized sudo attempts reported to?

When you attempt to use sudo, and are not allowed, a message says that the attempt will be reported.

Is this only reported in `/var/log/auth.log`? Is there another place? The reason I ask, is because the log contains so much that it's not a very good way of viewing often.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/838/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is reported in that file in ubuntu. It quite easy to change that. Just add this line in your `/etc/sudoers` file. Use `sudo visudo` to edit the file.

```
Defaults    logfile=/var/log/sudo.log
```

You can change the file name to whatever you think is appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

It is also sent by e-mail to root. If you want to have it sent to your user account instead, you can set an alias in `/etc/aliases`. In addition, if your system is configured properly to send e-mail to the outside world, you can alias it to any e-mail address. (To read e-mail sent to your local account, you can use, *e.g.*, `mutt`.)